# Service/database/technology to emulate long sequence object(not UUID)

Tags: java, architecture, sequence, apache-zookeeper, hazelcast

I'm looking for 3rdparty service in order to create/emulate something similar to a Postgres sequence database object.

I need this thread safe functionality in order to be able to ask it for next, unique `Long` value. I'm going to use this value as a surrogate key for my Spring Boot/Neoj4 application entities.

The main criterion is a speed. It should be pretty fast and durable(not only in memory but also persisted to HDD in order to survive after crashes and restarts)

Also, I don't want to go with `UUID` because I have to expose these IDs within my web application url parameters and in case of `UUID` my urls look awful. I want to go with a plain Long values for IDs.

Could you please suggest some database/service/technology that can be installed on my server and called for the unique IDs ?

**UPDATED**

Is it possible to implement fault-tolerant(persisted) AtomicLong sequence with Apache ZooKeeper or Hazelcast ? If so, is there any open source implementation of this solution that can be downloaded and used?

Comment: I'm not sure this is such a great idea.

First, speed. Type 1 UUID generation is much faster than Neo4j persistence. The overhead is negligible when the whole operation is considered.  Second, aesthetics. To avoid 'ugly' UUIDs, you're thinking of trading into a technical solution with more moving parts, whose failure modes probably are not fully understood (no disrespect to Snowcast), and which mandates a Hazelcast cluster. YMMV, but that's not a trade I would be tempted to make.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. Well.. could you please propose an alternative solution how to get reliable long values(like for example StackOverflow does) for my web urls ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like Snowflake (https://github.com/twitter/snowflake/releases/tag/snowflake-2010) or snowcast (https://github.com/noctarius/snowcast) might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Snowcast looks very interesting but it is not clear about fault-tolerant part of this service. For example in my system I can't lose the Sequencer number(for example after the crash of Snowcast) How Snowcast can guarantee that the sequence number will not be lost ?

Comment: For example I use MongoDB in my project. Can I use MongoDB as a backend data storage for Hazelcast in order to make Snowcast fault-tolerant ?

Comment: snowcast uses the millis part inside the id, therefore after failure your service would need to come back inside the same ms to get into the situation where you would regenerate the same id. ID are built from NODEID|MILLIS_OF_EPOCH|COUNTER

Comment: Thanks ! Could you please also show here at comment the typical ID value(just as example) generated by Snowcast ?

Comment: It is just a long value (positive / negative - imagine it an unsigned long) with those three components mentioned above build into certain bits of the long. The only important thing you need to remember: if your database doesn't have ulong support and doesn't allow negative long values you'll have a problem, apart from that it should work nicely. Hazelcast btw is just used to automatically assign node ids.

Comment: A few words on the background, this was designed for a gameserver system to provide unique IDs at high scale and low latency, unfortunately the project died before it was finished :)

Comment: @noctarius. The suggested solution is pretty cool. Is it possible to have duplicate generated IDs if after app restart, the EPOCH is set to same timestamp as before restart? For e.g:  EPOCH_OFFSET = 1388534400000 (2014-01-01--00:00:00)

Comment: The epoch timestamp should only be "created" once and reused forever. Imagine it as an offset of the unix timestamp to not run out quickly. In theory you could set offset to 0 and have a unix timestamp ;) The other option to get duplicate timestamps is to have the same node id assigned multiple times. Imagine the case a client disconnects but still works, the cluster restarts but the client doesn't reconnect, the node id might be reassigned. There's some randomization to lower the chance but it still exists.

Comment: @noctarius thanks for this clarification. One more question - the epoch timestamp should only be "created" once per application ? I mean should I configure epoch value for example in my application properties file or should I provide a new epoch value during every application start ? For example -   `SnowcastEpoch snowcastEpoch = SnowcastEpoch.byTimestamp(new Date().getTime());

  return snowcast.createSequencer("sequence_generator", snowcastEpoch);`

Comment: No it should be a constant values over the lifetime of the application. Multiple sequencers in the application can have different epochs though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want just numbers, why did you don't want to concatenate 2 longs from UUID ([`most`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#getMostSignificantBits()) + [`least`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#getLeastSignificantBits()))

According to your comment's question:
Yes, concatenated (not summed!) value from this methods with numbers filled leading `0` to full long length will gurantee all the same as `UUID` by itself (because it is kind of `UUID`s view).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a very interesting idea.. Will it work and guarantee pseudo uniqueness like UUID ?

Comment: Unfortunately the result value is also too long.. for example 40281202173729666258912159000741813434.. I'm still looking for a fault tolerant Service that will be able to quickly generate unique sequence for AtomicLong.